# What does `tar: Cannot connect to …: resolve failed` mean?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I'm writing a practice bash script that saves a folder as a tar archive with a name date-foldername.bak

The script fails when unformatted date is inserted as part of the filename, so `2022-05-09-work` is fine, but the default date output of `Mon  9 May 18:24:36 BST 2022` will produce:

```
  tar: Cannot connect to Mon  9 May 18: resolve failed
```

What does "resolve failed" mean in this context?

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Scrit accepts a folder name to back up as an parameter
# It saves the folder as a tar archive with the name date-foldername.bak 

echo "Beginning backup."
d=$(date)
echo "Today's date is $d"
tar --create --verbose --file="$d-$1.bak" "$1"
echo "Backup complete."
```

Answer (score 63):

From [`man 1 tar`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) [emphasis mine]:

> `-f`, `--file=ARCHIVE`
>
> Use archive file or device `ARCHIVE`. […]
>
> **An archive name that has a colon in it specifies a file or device on a remote machine.** The part before the colon is taken as the machine name or IP address, and the part after it as the file or device pathname […]
>
> `--force-local`
>
> Archive file is local even if it has a colon.

There are colons in `Mon 9 May 18:24:36 BST 2022`. `tar` "thinks" `Mon 9 May 18` is a machine name, it tries to resolve it. This fails. Use `--force-local`.

Note dates in this format are inconvenient for sorting (and not easily parsable). If this convinces you to change the format, remember you can create a format without colons in the first place. See `man 1 date` for details.

Comment: And be aware that you cannot save a file with a colon in its name on a Windows filesystem (FAT, VFAT, exFAT, NTFS).

Comment: @Dubu afaik, at least for NTFS, it does not disallow colons. Windows does, but not NTFS itself. Reading for example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/714607/how-to-open-files-with-colons-in-their-names-in-windows), Linux can create files on NTFS with colons. Although yes, it's a major pain to work with such files under Windows.

Comment: @JanDorniak It's the same with Windows' [reserved file names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Nothing in NTFS/exFAT/etc. actually stops you from naming a file `CON` or `NUL`, but you're not going to have a fun time trying to use them. If you want to avoid this problem, ntfs-3g has the `windows_names` mount option to prevent it. I'm not aware of any mount option on NTFS3 (from the kernel).

Comment: @ColeTobin NTFS3 is in a weird state right now - the guy who posted it, Konstantin Komarov, CEO of Paragon, went MIA shortly after the driver was merged, despite being the maintainer. I also read somewhere that he's Russian. No patches were merged after the original series. Last I read about it (in Phoronix coverage), there were talks about appointing a new maintainer (or several co-maintainers, if they step up). Seems like we'll wait a year or two more before it's in usable state.

Comment: Note that this misbehavior by tar is unique to GNU tar, at least among modern tar versions I'm aware of. You can just make a script named tar that does `exec /usr/bin/tar --force-local "$@"` and put it somewhere in the path before `/usr/bin` to fix it.

Answer (score 11):

Format your date so it doesn't break tar.

```
date +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

would work.